# Entity Framework, LINQ, and populating parent models and their children

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to EF/LINQ, and despite searching I can't seem to figure this out. I'm working with an existing database. I have Parents, and they have a one-to-many relationship with Children. I want to use the database to populate a list of the Parents *AND* populate their children. So in the end I'll have a collection of all the data for the parents, each of which has a list of children also populated with data. But I can't seem to get the parent-child relationship working. I know how to do this:

```
var query = (from p in myDbContext.Parents
              select p);
```

but that doesn't give me the Child data. I figured out how to do this:

```
var query = (from p in myDbContext.Parents join c in myDbContext.Children
            on p.Id equals c.ParentId into gj
            from sub in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select p);
```

but just like a left outer join, I get repeats of parent records when they have multiple children. I could loop through them to build the data I want piece by piece, but I'm guessing there's a way that's actually based on the relationship? I eventually will need to handle many-to-many's as well. My models are:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

    /* and a bunch of other fields */

    public Parent()
    {
        this.Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping:

```
public class ParentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            HasMany(t => t.Children)
                .WithRequired()
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.ParentId);

            this.Property(t => t.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.ToTable("Parents");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ParentId");
            this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

            /* and a bunch of other properties */
        }


}

public class ChildMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.ToTable("Children");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ChildId");
        this.Property(t => t.ParentId).HasColumnName("ParentId");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
    }

}
```

My data context:

```
public class myContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public myContext() :
        base("Name=myContext")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    static myContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<myContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ParentMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChildMap());
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are looking for `.Include()`

Then you can write :

```
var parents = myDbContext.Parents.Include(x => x.Children);
```

Or :

```
var parents = (from p in myDbContext.Parents.Include(x => x.Children) 
               select p)
```

Now the children will be included to the parent object.

Remeber to add "`using System.Data.Entity;`"

Comment: Both of those work, thanks! (Extra thanks for including the using with your answer -- it saved me more searching.)

Comment: I had the same issue when i started off with EF, it took a while for me to find the namespace. Glad i could help :)